# Recursive Function Not Outputting the Computation

Tags: list, recursion, scheme, racket

I've got to write a function that goes through sub-lists in a list and takes the first element in each one. I think I've got the solution right but I just don't get why it triggers my base case without outputting the elements first.

```
(define (sn-users graph)
(cond
  [(empty? graph)null]
  [else
   (caar graph)
   (sn-users (cdr graph))]))
```

This is what I've got and I just can't figure out what's wrong.
This is the output I get: ()

Note:
I'm only allowed to use side-effect free functions.

Comment: The value of the expression `(caar graph)` is ignored. Did you intend to store it in some result? Perhaps with the help of `cons`? (Hint, hint...)

Answer (score 1):

A Scheme `cond` has implicit begin. That means if were to rewrite your code using `if`. that hasn't, you'll need to write it like this:

```
; empty? and null are racket specific. Not Scheme code. 
(define (sn-users graph)
  (if (empty? graph)
      null 
      (begin
        (caar graph)
        (sn-users (cdr graph)))))
```

Problem with `begin` (and using explicit begin) is that all but the last expression is only for side effects. With `(caar graph)` it does nothing.

What you want is to make a list. You typically make lists with `cons` so I'm guessing that when calling `(sn-users '((1 2 3) (a b c) (I II III)))` your code should `(cons 1 (sn-users '((a b c) (I II III)))`.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You're very close but currently `(caar graph)` is discarded because you don't do anything with it.

```scm
(define (sn-users graph)
  (cond ((empty? graph) null)
        (else
         (cons (caar graph) ; cons first element onto recursive result
               (sn-users (cdr graph))))))

(sn-users
 '((alice 100)
   (bob 200)
   (charlie 300)))
```

```scm
; '(alice bob charlie)
```